# Limit of sequence: $\lim_{n\to\infty}({2n+1\over 3n})^n$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, limits-without-lhopital

$\lim_{n\to\infty}({2n+1\over 3n})^n$

For sufficiently large values of $n$:

$0\le ({2n+1\over 3n})^n\le({2\over 3})^n$,

From Squeeze theorem:
$\lim_{n\to\infty}({2n+1\over 3n})^n=0$

Is it ok?

I also tried to do this with formula: $\lim_{n\to\infty}(1+{a\over n})^n=e^a$, but with no effect.

Comment: You *never* have $$\frac{2n+1}{3n} \leq \frac{2}{3}$$ no matter how big $n$ is. Try $$\frac{2n+1}{3n} \leq \frac{2.5}{3}$$

Comment: When I changed $\ \frac{2}{3}$ to $ \frac{2.9999}{3}$ is it ok?

Comment: Yes, now it is. That is not great to change the question though, as it makes a couple answers addressing this very point obsolete.

Comment: Sorry. I fixed it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it is not correct, because the inequality $\left(\frac{2n+1}{3n}\right)^n\leqslant\left(\frac23\right)^n$ *never* holds. But you can use the fact that$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{2n+1}{3n}\right)^n=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac23\right)^n\times\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac1{2n}\right)^n=0.$$

Comment: I might be wrong but I don't think that it is wise to split limits this way. Doesn't always work (works this time though).

Comment: If it didn't work this time, I would not have written it.

Comment: True, but for educational purposes I'd say one shouldn't write things this way.

Answer (score 0):

Note that

$${2n+1\over 3n}\le{2\over 3}$$

is not true, use that eventually

$${2n+1\over 3n}\le \frac45<1 \iff 10n+5<12n \iff 2n>5$$

As a simpler alternative by root test

$$\sqrt[n]{a_n}=\sqrt[n]{\left({2n+1\over 3n}\right)^n}={2n+1\over 3n}\to\frac23<1\implies a_n \to 0$$

Comment: Which is not enough... since $1-1/n<1$ "eventually" (actually, always) as well. You need $< c$ for some *constant* $0\leq c<1$.

Comment: After the edit, fixing the solution, downvote removed. But you should really make sure your solution is correct **before** posting it (it's not the first time...).

Comment: @ClementC. Yes of course! the inequalities do not hold in the limit!

Answer (score 0):

Hint: in the original expression take out $\frac{2}{3}$ from your expression inside the brackets and then split.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the root test to get a result quite easily. Since $$\dfrac{2n+1}{3n}\to\dfrac{2}{3}<1$$
by the ratio test
$$\bigg(\dfrac{2n+1}{3n}\bigg)^n\to0.$$

Comment: I did not have it yet.